# What is the difference between getting a +delay value and -delay value

Tags: matlab

The transmitter signal is there in file ch1norm.csv
The receiver signal is there in file ch2norm.csv
There are 4000 sample values with a sampling time of 0.00000004sec.

**The problem is to find the delay between the transmitted and received signal.**

I have written the following code and trying to evaluate the delay using both cross-correlation and finddelay function.

```
D1=load('F:\PhD\SPS-3\DSO_Data\BPW34_R68K_T68ohm\One-meter\ALL0005\ch1norm.CSV');
D2=load('F:\PhD\SPS-3\DSO_Data\BPW34_R68K_T68ohm\One-meter\ALL0005\ch2norm.CSV');

[C21,lag21] = xcorr(D2(:,2),D1(:,2));
[A,I]=max(abs(C21));
t21 = lag21(I); %Delay using xcorr
delay1=finddelay(D1(:,2),D2(:,2)); %Delay using finddelay function.
```

I am getting a delay of 59 samples.
The following are my questions-

1. What is the difference between getting a +delay value and a -ve delay value
2. How can we evaluate BER from these sample value

Comment: Well, positive is one direction, negative the other. What is BER?

Comment: A delay in a signal does not mean there is been errors in the sending of the signal, so BER is confusing thing to mention. You will need to be much more clear.